# How to mock static method in LocalDate using Spock?

Tags: java, spock

I wanna mock `LocalDate.now()` to return each time the same date.

For this I tried two different options:

First : `LocalDate.now() >> LocalDate.of(2020, 05, 07)`

Second:

```
def today = GroovyMock(LocalDate) {
                  getYear() >> 2020
                  getMonth() >> Month.APRIL
                  getDayOfMonth() >> 24
                  getDayOfWeek() >> DayOfWeek.FRIDAY
                }
    LocalDate.now(timeZone) >> today
```

But it does not help me, `LocalDate.now()` still return the current date when it calls in the code. How I can achieve that LocalDate.now() every time return me the mock date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. The `Clock` class exists for *exactly* this reason. In the class under test, add a property with a setter:

```
private Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();
```

and use

```
LocalDate.now(clock)
```

In your test case, replace the default "real clock" with a test clock:

```
subject.clock = Clock.fixed(specificInstant, UTC)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to mock static methods of Java classes in Spock using on-board tools. If you really want that - and I agree with chrylis that you don't - you would need to use an addititonal tool such as PowerMock or Sarek (one of my own pet projects, still not officially released, but available on GitHub).

Background: Groovy mocks, as the name implies, only work with Groovy classes. Using them with Java classes makes them behave like regular Spock mocks, i.e. stubbing static methods has no effect. this is documented [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#GroovyMocks):

> When Should Groovy Mocks be Favored over Regular Mocks? Groovy mocks should be used when the code under specification is written in Groovy *and* some of the unique Groovy mock features are needed. **When called from Java code, Groovy mocks will behave like regular mocks.** Note that it isn’t necessary to use a Groovy mock merely because the code under specification and/or mocked type is written in Groovy. Unless you have a concrete reason to use a Groovy mock, prefer a regular mock.